# The API tells me ,I will get a json response ,but i am getting None

Tags: python, digital-ocean

I am trying to create a droplet in Digital Ocean.The API tells me the response of `.create` is a JSON object. As I run this query a droplet is created succesfully in my DigitalOcean account, but I am getting only `None` as the response. What is the problem?

```
import digitalocean
droplet = digitalocean.Droplet(token="<<<TOKEN>>>",
                                   name='DanyshOcean',
                                   region='nyc2', # New York 2
                                   image='ubuntu-14-04-x64', # Ubuntu 14.04 x64
                                   size_slug='512mb',  # 512MB
                                   backups=True)
    jsonobj=droplet.create()
    print(jsonobj)
```

Output:

`None`

Comment: What did you expect it to return? The `Droplet.create` method always returns `None`. The REST API and the interface of the wrapper library are two different things.

Comment: How do i make possible that at creation of droplet ,i get in response the status of the droplet ,created or not ?

Answer (score 0):

`droplet.create()` will create the droplet and `droplet` itself is an object that has the attributes of the new droplet.

Try for example:

`print(droplet.id)`
or 
`droplet.destroy()`

Answer (score 0):

The Digital Ocean REST API is different than the python library (which probably uses the API under the covers).

If you read the [library docs](https://github.com/koalalorenzo/python-digitalocean#checking-the-status-of-the-droplet) you'll see that you need to use the `status`:

```
actions = droplet.get_actions()
for action in actions:
    action.load()
    # Once it shows complete, droplet is up and running
    print(action.status)
```

Once there's a `complete` status, your droplet is up. I don't know if this blocks and waits for your droplet to complete, so you might need to do something like this:

```
import time

running = False
while not running:
    print('Waiting 1s for droplet to start up...')
    time.sleep(1)
    actions = droplet.get_actions()
    for action in actions:
        action.load()
        if action.status == 'complete':
            running = True
```

Comment: @Rhymoid so the rest api uses the python library under the covers?

Comment: I don't know what went wrong there, but I somehow read that you wrote that O_o

Comment: @Rhymoid probably just too early there.  Or late ;)